# Sonar runner: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home folder

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

**Situation** : I installed Sonarqube on a Win XP 32-bit system. I set all paths as instructed. The server opens up well at localhost://9090.

My JAVA_HOME is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60;

**Problem** When I run, sonar-runner.bat, I get the following error:

ERROR: Java_Home exists but does not point to a valid Java home folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found here.

**What I tried:** I added /bin to the path. I tried /jre, and then /jre/bin (Note: all of them contain the "/bin/java.exe" within them.

Is this due to some permissions issue of the Java (or Jdk) folder ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the semicolon `;` from the end; right now it's being included in the constructed path.

This variable is expected to be a single directory, not a list, and should not have a path separator.